# How do I do a Update Query on another Query MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this Query:

```
SELECT notiser.notis AS notis
    , skapare.kategoriId
    , skapare.kategori AS kategori 
FROM notiser, skapare, anvandare 
WHERE skapare.kategori = 2 
    AND skapare.kategoriId =  448 
    AND skapare.id = notiser.skapareId 
    AND anvandare.id = skapare.anvandareId;
```

It gives me the Result:

```
notis   kategoriId  kategori
Hello!      448     2
Hello2!     448     2
Hello3!     448     2
```

I want to change the value of the "kategori" to 3, on just these specific results.

Is it possible?

Im using PHP and mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the same `FROM` and `WHERE` in the `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE notiser, skapare, anvandare 
SET skapare.kategori = 3
WHERE skapare.kategori = 2 
    AND skapare.kategoriId =  448 
    AND skapare.id = notiser.skapareId 
    AND anvandare.id = skapare.anvandareId;
```

Comment: Yea this works! The other answers also helped but i got a synax error. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely following, but why not constrain `skapare.kategori` to `3`

```
SELECT notiser.notis AS notis
    , skapare.kategoriId
    , skapare.kategori AS kategori 
FROM notiser, skapare, anvandare 
WHERE skapare.kategori = 3 
    AND skapare.kategoriId =  448 
    AND skapare.id = notiser.skapareId 
    AND anvandare.id = skapare.anvandareId;
```

**Update**
I think I understand now:

```
UPDATE skapare SET skapare.kategori = 3 WHERE skapare.id IN(SELECT notiser.skapareId
FROM notiser, skapare, anvandare 
WHERE skapare.kategori = 2
    AND skapare.kategoriId =  448 
    AND skapare.id = notiser.skapareId 
    AND anvandare.id = skapare.anvandareId);
```

Comment: He wants to `UPDATE` `skapare.kategori` to be 3.

Comment: I want the Change the value in the database, not to show the value with "3" in skapare.kategori

Answer (score 0):

assume that you have an `id` column in `skapare` table to indentify single rows, then you can use the following query:

```
UPDATE skapare set kategori=3
WHERE skapare.id IN
    (SELECT skapare.id 
     FROM notiser, skapare, anvandare 
     WHERE skapare.kategori = 2 
        AND skapare.kategoriId =  448 
        AND skapare.id = notiser.skapareId 
        AND anvandare.id = skapare.anvandareId);
```